# The boundaries are getting offset upon resize

Tags: layout, html, scroll, scrollbar

I've got some problem with css, the content is sticking out from the boundaries.
It is expected to have a scrollbar rather than hidden overflow, but the boundaries.
Please help.

Here's the code, which reflects my CSS structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>

body{
border:3px solid #FFAD17;
background-color:#FFF;
border-radius:7px;
font:9.5pt Tahoma;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
html {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

div.header{
    background-color:yellow;
    background-position:top;
    padding: 3px;
    }
div.wrapper{
    float:left;
    }
div.context_wrapper{
    margin-left:158px;
    padding: 3px;   
    }
div.context{
    float:left;
    }
div.menu{
    text-align:center;
    padding: 3px;
    width:140px;
    float:left;     
    }
div.footer{
    background-color:yellow;
    background-position:bottom;
    width:auto;
    padding: 3px;
    clear:both;     
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="header">Head</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="menu">Menu</div>
    <div class="context_wrapper">
        <div class="context">
            ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">Foot</div>
</body>

</html>
```

[a busy cat http://img215.imageshack.us/img215/6065/20120223132157.png](http://img215.imageshack.us/img215/6065/20120223132157.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shouldn't style the body element like it was a `<div>` element, better to make a new wrapper. Furthermore, from your question I gather you're looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/SQDXt/

Basically, this adds the wrapper div with the scrollbar when your content exceeds the size of the wrapper. Also, the header and footer are within the second wrapper, to span the whole width when the content exceeds the first wrapper's width.

Comment: Wow, this looks like a cool thing! I will test it out right away, there is one small objection though: the yellow stripes (ie footer, header) are supposed to take all the width, all the way through.

Comment: I'll try it out and apply to my styles.

Comment: The stripes are ok, when I applied to my code, just a sec, I will apply it to my entire site, and see the actual output.

Comment: I don't know if you're using a fixed width or liquid layout (i.e. total page width in pixels or relative to users screen width) but you can try floating the first wrapper: http://jsfiddle.net/SQDXt/1/.

Comment: Well, its almost working, thanks!
Though there is still some problem with stripes, thats how it does:
[link](http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/8715/2012022317204.png)

Comment: Well I'll try to explain, the size of the content div does not change once it's outputted, its not stretching in any way. But as each page has different content, they all end up with different width.

Comment: Thanks! It's even better with float:left, as it gets a normal scrollbar at the bottom just as intended. Might as well use overflow:hidden so it doesn't get double scroll bar.

Comment: Aha, I just got what you meant about liquid layout... Yeah, ideally the borders should take a whole with of the window like it was initially. Its a minor thing, but it would be cool to take care of :-)

Comment: Please go ahead, if have an idea about that, but as of I know I belive the main question is resolved. Much thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome. You'll probably keep on fiddling with the css, but that is a good thing. That way you'll discover and learn what works and how the html structure and css rules work together.